# Load objects in C (cluster analyzis)

Tags: c, structure, scanf

I am making program, that should do **cluster analysis**, but one of my function does not work. In this function I am trying to **load objects** (structure, which contains `int ID` (of cluster), `float x` (position) and `float y` (position), and add them to **clusters** (structure - `int size` (actual number of objects that are in it), `capacity` (maximum number of containable objects) and field of objects (with objects in it)

This is my function now

```
assert(arr != NULL);

// TODO
int res = 0;
FILE* stream = fopen(filename, "r");
/*if (stream == NULL)
{
    return res;
}*/
int cnt = 0;
fscanf(stream, "count=%d\n", &cnt);

struct cluster_t ** tmpArr;
tmpArr = calloc(cnt,sizeof(struct cluster_t));
//struct obj_t * tmpObj;
struct cluster_t *Cluster = NULL;


int pos = 0;
int id;
float x, y;
while(cnt != 0)
{
    fscanf(stream,"%d %f %f\n", &id, &x, &y);
    printf("%d %f %f", id, x, y);
    init_cluster(Cluster, CLUSTER_CHUNK);
    Cluster->obj[res].id = id;
    Cluster->obj[res].x = x;
    Cluster->obj[res].y = y;
    Cluster->size = 1;
    tmpArr[pos] = Cluster;
    res++;
    pos++;
    cnt--;

}
```

If value of returned integer will be 0, then there is problem with loading.

But, somehow when I try debugging, I get **SIGSEGV** at

```
Cluster->obj[res].id = id;
```

Any idea? Thanks very much

For those who are asking, this is `init_cluster`

```
void init_cluster(struct cluster_t *c, int cap)

c = calloc(cap,sizeof(struct obj_t)); 
if(c!= NULL)
{
    c->capacity = cap; 
    c->size = 0; 
    c->obj = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `init_cluster(Cluster, CLUSTER_CHUNK);` Cluster (pointer) is passed by value. (the function presumably allocates and assigns to a local variable) You *could* add a `assert(Cluster != NULL);` after the function call

Comment: That's true, you should post the whole code so that people can try it out. Or at least a snippet containing all the functionality you need to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @joop  I would, if I can, i am making it as a school project and I can't post whole code, because rules.. But if you want, I can add Init_cluster

Comment: @Brky yes please post the whole `Init_cluster` function, not just a few lines. If you don't want to post the whole function for whatever reason, please post at least the very first line `void Init_cluster(...)`. That would defininitely help.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You have it :)

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question; together with the answers it forms a collective work under the CC-wiki license you agreed to when you posted on this site.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic pitfall and has been answered dozens of times.

Parameters are passed by value in C:

This is wrong:

```
void init_cluster(struct cluster_t *c, int cap)
{
   c = calloc(cap,sizeof(struct obj_t));   
 // ^ this modifies the local c variable but not the 
//    Cluster variable on the calling side
}
```

You need this:

```
void init_cluster(struct cluster_t **c, int cap)
{
   *c = calloc(cap,sizeof(struct obj_t));   
 // ^ this modifies the local c variable but not the 
//    Cluster variable on the calling side

    (*c)->obj....
}
```

and call it like this:

```
init_cluster(&Cluster, CLUSTER_CHUNK);
```

instead of:

```
init_cluster(Cluster, CLUSTER_CHUNK);
```

---

Think of a simpler example:

```
void ComputeDoubleValue(int value)
{
   value = value * 2;
}
```

Now if you call:

```
int a = 5;
ComputeDoubleValue(a);
```

`a` will still be `5` instead of `10`:

You would need this:

```
void ComputeDoubleValue(int *value)
{
   *value = *value * 2;
}

int a = 5;
ComputeDoubleValue(&a);
```

Comment: Error message when I changed *c = calloc....
`L:\proj3\main.c|87|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct cluster_t' from type 'void *'`

Comment: If compiles fine here. You forgot something, read my answer carefully.

Comment: He is probably using a C++ compiler. (or he forgot one `*` somewhere)

Comment: I'd rather say he forgot to change `void init_cluster(struct cluster_t *c,..)` to `void init_cluster(struct cluster_t **c`.